# am i allowed to use member variables in static inner class for fragments?

Tags: java, android

All my static fragments are:

```
public static class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
             int somenum;
             String name;
}
```

are the values of `somenum` and `name` shared  between different instances because the class is static?

Comment: No, they're not shared.  (You could just have tried this.)

Comment: i made a complex activity use non static fragment classes, now i have to refactor and wanted to verify. i guess i could have created a new fragment to test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are the values of somenum and name shared between different instances because the class is static?

No. If you want them shared, declare the *members* `static`:

```
public static class Inner  {
             static int somenum;
             static String name;
}
```

The `static` modifier on a class is only valid on [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), and its job there is to say that the nested class is not an *inner* class (a class that's tied to an *instance* of its containing class). It has nothing to do with whether the members of that class are static.

Comment: so static inner class vs non static is just an accessibility thing?

Comment: @tipu: Not in the usual sense of `public`/`private`/etc. An inner class (non-static nested class) is tied to an instance of the outer class. They're commonly used for iterator classes, for instance; they have access to instance members of instances of the containing class. A static nested class is primarily an organizational thing, vaguely similar to packages; `Map.Entry` is a reasonable example. See the linked tutorial for details.